# Multiple comparisons on nested subsets of data for a non-parametric test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

My problem: I'm using data sets where some are nested in a non-parametric test that expects independent data sets. How can I correct for that in a way that is reasonable? Or even better: What would the correct approach be here?

**In detail:**

I want to compare multiple classification algorithms (alg_1, ..., alg_k) on multiple data sets (set_1, ..., set_m) of genome-wide association studies (GWAS). The data sets themselves are pre-filtered to contain only markers (SNPs) reaching a certain p-value threshold after testing them for association with the phenotype. There are 6 different thresholds.

I went with the [Friedman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test), a rank test, because the results are not normally distributed. The data looks like this, values are `performance_measure(rank)`:

```
data set    alg_1       alg_2       ... alg_k
set_1 e-3   0.57(1.0)   0.55(5.0)   ... 0.56(2.0)
set_1 e-4   0.60(1.0)   0.56(4.0)   ... 0.58(3.0)
...
set_2 e-3   0.88(2.0)   0.80(5.0)   ... 0.85(3.0)
set_2 e-4   0.93(1.0)   0.82(4.0)   ... 0.85(3.0)
...
set_m e-3   0.77(1.0)   0.76(2.0)   ... 0.70(4.0)
set_m e-4   0.78(1.5)   0.78(1.5)   ... 0.75(5.0)
...
avg. rank   1.87        4.10        ... 3.78
```

I already evaluated the results, performed post-hoc tests and so on, but I now I think that I made it myself to easy. The parameters of the Friedman test are number of rows/data sets (*n*) and number of columns/treatments (*k*), but I'm unsure on what is a justifiable value for *n*.

1. If I use the number of rows $n=m*6$, I violate the assumption that all data sets are independent, because each group of 6 are nested subsets.
2. If I use the number of data sets $n=m$, I don't violate the independence assumption, but I may be too conservative.
3. Alternatively, I can chose another multiplier like $n=m*3$ or $n=m*2$, but then it is hard to justify why I chose that specific method.

Additionally, the ranks are calculated from $m*6$ data points, so I'm not sure that I can just change the degrees of freedom (*n*) like that.

I tried all four variants and p-value of the Friedman test is something like

- $n=m*6$: $p < 10^{-14}$
- $n=m*3$: $p < 10^{-14}$
- $n=m*2$: $p \approx 1*10^{-11}$
- $n=m\ \ \ \ \ $: $p \approx 4*10^{-5}$

which is fine, but I have other, more specific experimental settings with less data points where it is less obvious, which would also have to be corrected for multiple testing again, like this:

- $n=m*6$: $p \approx 6 * 10^{-8}$
- $n=m*3$: $p \approx 3 * 10^{-4}$
- $n=m*2$: $p \approx 0.005$
- $n=m\ \ \ \ \ $: $p \approx 0.09$

These are, of course, only examples of the significant results, the vast majority of experiments yields no significance at all.

I'm at a loss here. I need a way of evaluating these results that satisfies both the reviewers and my own standards for scientific procedure.

(**Note:** There already is a [question with basically the same title](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/multiple-comparisons-on-nested-subsets-of-data), but it unfortunately is something completely different than what I'm struggling with.)